# VisualSVN on Windows 2012 - how to run "svnadmin hotcopy" (getting Access is Denied)

Tags: windows-server-2012, visualsvn-server, svn

Following this as a guide:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-subversion-repositories

I've tried the following commmands:

```
svnadmin hotcopy "C:\Repositories" > "C:\BackupSVN"

svnadmin hotcopy "C:\Repositories\*" > "C:\BackupSVN"

svnadmin hotcopy "C:\Repositories\TestRepo1" > "C:\BackupSVN"
```

However all 3 commands result in "Access is denied"

I've tried them at an "Administrator" command prompt as well, still the same error.

SO:

How can I properly run an svnadmin hotcopy command (or even svnadmin dump) on a Windows 2012 server?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grrr...I figured it out.  Stupid default UAC on Windows 2012.

> Deactivating UAC in Windows 2008 R2 was possible via running msconfig
>   (for example winkey+r -> msconfig), going to the Tools tab and
>   launching "Change UAC settings". There, you select "Never notify" to
>   disable UAC. The same approach is still available in Windows Server
>   2012, though UAC is still active after you selected "Never notify".
>   You have the option to turn off UAC via registry by changing the DWORD
>   "EnableLUA" from 1 to 0 in
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system".
>   You will get a notification that a reboot is required. After the
>   reboot, UAC is disabled.

[image: UAC dialog]

[image: UAC regedit]

CREDIT: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx

Comment: What is UAC and how did you solved the UAC?

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan - I'll update my answer with details.

Comment: @AlbertoSpelta - not sure what you are talking about.  This question was about getting the command to run properly (which I did), not about what "hotcopy" does.  Not sure why you even posted a comment here.

Comment: Alternatively you can just run the "svnadmin hotcopy" as Administrator (run it from cmd.exe or PowerShell that was run as Administrator). Disabling UAC is pretty drastic IMO.